# Why hasn't my question been deleted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-questions

I asked a [lame question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617553/do-rails-development-while-serving-not-localhost). It was closed, and quite correctly. I'm embarrassed by it, I want it to go away. I can't delete it because it has answers. I've flagged it for deletion a couple of times, but nothing happens.

Please make it go away.

Comment: I _almost_ deleted it, as there's no _real_ loss for any involved, but I don't want to set precedence for meta being a catalyst to get a moderator to cast a _binding_ delete vote. If the community agrees that there's no real loss, they will vote to delete it for you. Additionally, you can request that you be disassociated from the post.

Comment: I know nothing about Rails, but it seems from my reading like a problem that someone else might have, i.e., that someone might make the same incorrect assumption that you did. Is that definitely not the case?

Comment: @Bart Don't disagree with your decision to close, but your edit is kinda silly.

Comment: I disagree. If your question is to remain, the current title is more likely to be a successful search result.

Answer (score 6):

You can ask to get your name removed from it, if you're *that* embarassed by it. I've seen worse though, so it's probably not worth the effort. It has already been closed, so it is effectively out of circulation and won't be getting in anyone's way. Nevertheless, if the community feels the harm from your question outweighs the benefits from the answers, they will vote to delete the question.

Also, you're being a little selfish here. Two users voluntarily invested time and effort into writing answers to your question. For all you know they could be very proud of their answers, so it would be inconsiderate to delete their answers along with the question *just* because you are embarrassed (although, as I mentioned earlier, it may be deleted by the community if enough people feel it adds no value to the site).

Comment: If you think the answers are worth keeping, you should vote to re-open. Closed questions are on the road to deletion; keeping questions that don't fit in on the site (except for those that deserve historical locks) doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: No, the closing of a question is independent of the quality of the answers. I have seen some awful questions get good answers. Yep, they deserve a lock. But locks aren't used that much, keeping them closed seems OK. "On the road to deletion" well, that depends. That's only for unsalvageable questions, really, though on SO, deletion is far more aggressive.

Comment: @Manishearth: We close questions because, for some reason or another, they are not appropriate for the site. Why would we _not_ remove something that's not appropriate for the site?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Because the answers get removed as well. And _those_ may be appropriate for the site. In some cases, I've seen crap questions with great answers (maybe not this one, in which case I guess deletion was OK). Many times, the answerers interpret the question their way, and write long, useful answers for it. I've seen this happen _a lot_ on [physics.se].

Comment: So, answers can justify a question's existence, hm, @Manishearth?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Yes, they _can_ :/

Comment: @JoshCaswell [Here's](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52353/what-is-a-closed-system-generally-in-nature-including-outer-space-for-any-eleme) a NARQ that got answered anyway, with a good answer. I'm not deleting that.

Comment: I agree that questions sometimes should be kept because the answers are great, @Manishearth. I disagree that they should be kept and _left closed_.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: We'll have to agree to disagree here then :) I'm not reopening the question I linked to. It is pretty hard to figure out what he's asking, and, besides, he's pushing an agenda. The question won't be salvaged unless he edits it himself to a form where we know what he's talking about. The answer is basically a good guess of the meaning of the q.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, other users have put effort into answering your question. It won't be deleted. You can, however, ask for it to be dissociated from your account. (use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page)

Comment: But the whole question is based on facts that I got wrong. What value are solutions to a non-existent problem?

Comment: If you think the answers are worth keeping, you should vote to re-open. Closed questions are on the road to deletion; keeping questions that don't fit in on the site (except for those that deserve historical locks) doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch: Depends. Not all answers may be just bare-bones "solutions" (in this case, though, they were). They may explain some concepts as well. I've had quite a few of my own problems solved from threads on SO/SE which were on a _different_ problem.

Answer (score 0):

I voted to delete it.  If a couple of other people do the same, it will be deleted.